# How many times do two circles intersect?

Tags: curves, plane-geometry, convex-geometry

Suppose you have two compact convex sets $A,B \subset \mathbb R^2$. Their interiors intersect, but neither is contained in the other. Do the boundaries intersect in at least two distinct points?

Obviously in general the intersection might be a singleton. Take two discs tangent to each other:

[image]

But in this case the interiors are disjoint, so it doesn't count. I am interested in the case where the interiors intersect. Like this:

[image]

Here you can see the boundaries intersect exactly twice. In fact we can get four intersections easily enough:

[image]

Is it easy to prove there are always at least 2 distinct intersections?

Comment: That second blue image onward is not a circle. (Actual) circles in the plane always intersect at 0, 1 or 2 points. This no longer applies when one of the circles becomes something else (in this case, an ellipse)

Comment: Related: [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem).

Comment: Your title is not the same as your question!

Comment: @TonyK What would you call the set $\{x \in \mathbb R^2: \|x-a\|=1\}$ for an arbitrary norm?

Comment: @Daron: Not a circle! That is a Euclidean construct.

Comment: @TonyK Don't give me problems. Give me solutions.

Comment: Now you're just being stupid.

Comment: @TonyK Not Smart!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some point $p_1$ on the boundary of $A$ is in the interior of $B$, and some point $p_2$ on the boundary of $A$ that is not in $B$.  As you go along the boundary of $A$ from $p_1$ to $p_2$, you must hit the boundary of $B$ at some point. But there are two ways (disjoint except for the endpoints) to go from $p_1$ to $p_2$ on the boundary, so two such points.